# My app crashed when launched

Tags: java, android, crash

I write some simple game like a hit-the-cat. But it crashed when I run it. And I really don't understand why.

**MainActivity.java**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private static final long duration = 50000;
    private static final long interval = 1500;

    private ImageView[][] gameField = {{(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.enemy1_1),(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.enemy1_2),(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.enemy1_3)},
            {(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.enemy2_1),(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.enemy2_2),(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.enemy2_3)},
            {(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.enemy3_1),(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.enemy3_2),(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.enemy3_3)}};


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        GameCountDownTimer gameCountDownTimer = new GameCountDownTimer(duration, interval);
        gameCountDownTimer.start();
    }

    public class GameCountDownTimer extends CountDownTimer {

        Game game = new Game();
        ImageView imgLose = (ImageView)findViewById(R.drawable.cat_sing); //Lost cat
        ImageView imgTouch = (ImageView)findViewById(R.drawable.cat_pirate); //Touched cat


        public GameCountDownTimer(long duration, long interval) {
            super(duration, interval);    
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {

            for (int i = 0; i < Game.rows; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < Game.cols; j++) {

                    gameField[i][j].setImageResource(0);

                }
            }

            Toast resultToast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You missed " + game.gameScore() + " cats:)",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            resultToast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
            resultToast.show();

        }

        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

            boolean[][] newEnemies = game.generateEnemy();
            int score = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < Game.rows; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < Game.cols; j++) {

                    if (gameField[i][j].getResources() == imgLose.getResources()) {
                        score++;                             //Если кот пропущен, увеличиваем счетчик
                    }

                    if (gameField[i][j].getResources() == imgTouch.getResources()) {
                        gameField[i][j].setImageResource(0); //Убираемся за отшлепанными котами
                    }

                    if (newEnemies[i][j]) {
                        gameField[i][j].setImageResource(R.drawable.cat_sing); //Выпускаем новых котов
                    }

                }
            }
            game.setScore(score);

        }
    }
}
```

**Game.java**

```
import java.util.Random;

/**
 * User: Bringoff
 * Date: 30.10.13
 * Time: 8:07
 */
public class Game {

    static final int cols = 3;
    static final int rows = 3;
    private int score;
    private boolean[][] arEnemies = null;

    public int results = 0;

    public void setScore(int score) {
        this.score+= score;
    }
    public int gameScore() {
        return score;
    }

    public boolean[][] generateEnemy() {
        arEnemies = new boolean[rows][cols];
        Random random = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; i < cols; j++) {
                arEnemies[i][j] = random.nextBoolean();
            }
        }

        return arEnemies;
    }

}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
 <TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/main_l">


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/results_view"
        android:id="@+id/tvResults"
        android:layout_weight="0.75"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="28dp"
        android:typeface="normal"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" />

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/enemy1_1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:onClick="enemies_onClick"></ImageView>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/enemy1_2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:onClick="enemies_onClick"></ImageView>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/enemy1_3"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:onClick="enemies_onClick"></ImageView>

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/enemy2_1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:onClick="enemies_onClick"></ImageView>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/enemy2_2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:onClick="enemies_onClick"></ImageView>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/enemy2_3"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:onClick="enemies_onClick"></ImageView>

        </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/enemy3_1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:onClick="enemies_onClick"></ImageView>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/enemy3_2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:onClick="enemies_onClick"></ImageView>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/enemy3_3"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:onClick="enemies_onClick"></ImageView>

        </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

log of crashing:

> 11-01 09:44:23.810: D/dalvikvm(18847): Late-enabling CheckJNI
> 11-01 09:44:23.910: D/AndroidRuntime(18847): Shutting down VM
> 11-01 09:44:23.910: W/dalvikvm(18847): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x416f6700)
> 11-01 09:44:23.910: E/AndroidRuntime(18847): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> 11-01 09:44:23.910: E/AndroidRuntime(18847): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.bringoff.touchthemall/com.bringoff.touchthemall.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
> 11-01 09:44:23.910: E/AndroidRuntime(18847):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2137)
> 11-01 09:44:23.910: E/AndroidRuntime(18847):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
> 11-01 09:44:23.910: E/AndroidRuntime(18847):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
> 11-01 09:44:23.910: E/AndroidRuntime(18847):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
> 11-01 09:44:23.910: E/AndroidRuntime(18847):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
> 11-01 09:44:23.910: E/AndroidRuntime(18847):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
> 11-01 09:44:23.910: E/AndroidRuntime(18847):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
> 11-01 09:44:23.910: E/AndroidRuntime(18847):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
> 11-01 09:44:23.910: E/AndroidRuntime(18847):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
> 11-01 09:44:23.910: E/AndroidRuntime(18847):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
> 11-01 09:44:23.910: E/AndroidRuntime(18847):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
> 11-01 09:44:23.910: E/AndroidRuntime(18847):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
> 11-01 09:44:23.910: E/AndroidRuntime(18847): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
> 11-01 09:44:23.910: E/AndroidRuntime(18847):    at android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:1853)
> 11-01 09:44:23.910: E/AndroidRuntime(18847):    at com.bringoff.touchthemall.MainActivity.(MainActivity.java:17)
> 11-01 09:44:23.910: E/AndroidRuntime(18847):    at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
> 11-01 09:44:23.910: E/AndroidRuntime(18847):    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1130)
> 11-01 09:44:23.910: E/AndroidRuntime(18847):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
> 11-01 09:44:23.910: E/AndroidRuntime(18847):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2128)
> 11-01 09:44:23.910: E/AndroidRuntime(18847):    ... 11 more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not initialize component at before setting the content view.

You can set it like:

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

        private static final long duration = 50000;
        private static final long interval = 1500;

     // ID of Image View
public static int[] CellID=new int[]{
         R.id.mycell01,R.id.mycell02,R.id.mycell03,R.id.mycell04,
         R.id.mycell05,R.id.mycell06,R.id.mycell07,R.id.mycell08,R.id.mycell09};
     // Image View name
static ImageView img01,img02,img03,img04,img05,img06,img07,img08,img09;
    // Array of ImageView
public static ImageView[] ImageViewImg=new ImageView[]{
        img01,img02,img03,img04,img05,img06,img07,img08,img09};


        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    for (int i = 0; i < ImageViewImg.length; i++) {
            ImageViewImg[i]=(ImageView)findViewById(CellID[i]);


        }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

SO is not a debugger, but since your error is ridiculously silly:

You are trying to use findViewById before setContentView!

This code executes before onCreate:

```
private ImageView[][] gameField = {{(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.enemy1_1),(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.enemy1_2),(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.enemy1_3)},
            {(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.enemy2_1),(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.enemy2_2),(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.enemy2_3)},
            {(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.enemy3_1),(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.enemy3_2),(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.enemy3_3)}};
```

All you have to do is change the code before to

```
private ImageView[][] gameField;
```

and add after setContentView:

```
gameField = new ImageView[][]{{(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.enemy1_1),(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.enemy1_2),(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.enemy1_3)},
                {(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.enemy2_1),(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.enemy2_2),(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.enemy2_3)},
                {(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.enemy3_1),(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.enemy3_2),(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.enemy3_3)}};
```

Comment: "Array constants can only be used in initializers", eclipse said

Comment: Oh, sorry, I see. how could I forget it?.. But I learn java and android a coule of days)

Comment: Em... It still crushed.

Comment: @Izobara. It is a different error for sure. Ask a different question

Answer (score 0):

you cannot do that

> private ImageView[][] gameField =
>   {{(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.enemy1_1),(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.enemy1_2),(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.enemy1_3)},
>               {(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.enemy2_1),(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.enemy2_2),(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.enemy2_3)},
>               {(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.enemy3_1),(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.enemy3_2),(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.enemy3_3)}};

you should save only the id , R.id.XXX
and when query the view use findViewById.

you cannot query view by id if the view doesnt yet exists.

Answer (score 0):

You need to move all your initialization inside `onCreate` after `setContentView`

```
ImageView iv;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); // must be first
    iv =(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.enemy1_1);  // then initialization
    //  same for the rest of the initializations
```

Without inflating layout you can't use `findViewById` to initialize views. If not you get `NullPointerException`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here.

```
private ImageView[][] gameField = {{(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.enemy1_1),(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.enemy1_2),(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.enemy1_3)},
        {(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.enemy2_1),(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.enemy2_2),(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.enemy2_3)},
        {(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.enemy3_1),(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.enemy3_2),(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.enemy3_3)}};
```

You can not initialise variables these as fields..you must put them in the onCreate() method. The method findViewById() can only be used after the onCreate...more specifically, after the setContentView() is called (in the onCreate).